HTTP audio streaming
Is it possible to provide audio file from HTTP server that is consumed by clients via streaming (loading a file partially)?
HTTP server shouldn't care about streaming, it thinks consumers just normally download its files.
I guess web browsers work this way but not sure.

Progressive download looks like what I need.
It loads a file partially making an illusion of streaming and it doesn't need HTTP server to care about streaming.

This is correct, and I'm hoping this question is re-opened as I'd be happy to explain some of the more subtle technical details here.  Long story short, the media player will put back pressure on the stream, which bubbles through the user agent, all the way to the TCP socket, where the window size is eventually reduced to zero.  This is no different than a slow client, so the server needs no specific implementation.  There are some servers that will only stay in this condition for a limited period of time, causing the browser to reconnect and pick up where it left off.
